# Java spring does not read properly values from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a really difficult problem with `application.properties` file because I can not read properly from this file with java spring. The simple source code is given below. Thank you in advance.

**`application.properties file`**

```
message.username=john12345
```

**`Messages.java`**

```
@Value("${message.username}")
private String username;
```

It throws a `FileNotFoundException` and shows that the value is always `null`.

Comment: Have you configured propertyconfigurer?

Comment: Using context namespace there is proprtyplaceholder element?

Comment: Then show the code ?

Comment: The actual problem is that the value always returns null. I do not use any applicationContext.xml.

Comment: Where do you have _application.properties_ stored? When do you check if the `username` is null? Is the class containint the `username` field a Spring bean/component?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch The application.properties file is saved in resources folder. The username returns null value instead of selected value. What do you mean by saying spring bean/component? What do you think I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am asking because it might be that you want to use the `username` from within the constructor. It may be that the class that has the `username` field is not managed by Spring. Without showing more of the code it's hard to help you.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I simply use username inside a static method. I am not using anything else. I can share the code, but it is very simple to understand it.

Comment: without the code nobody will be able to help you. The problem you have is: is the class with the property managed by Spring, and how do yo access it. As you are not sharing the necessary information and code, you'll be out of luck with getting help here.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Maybe you did not understand my error. Please look at this line of error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\filesystem\null (The system cannot find the file specified). The problem that I do not understand is that always the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure `property-placeholder` in your spring context:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:my.properties"/
```

Comment: not necessary with spring boot, as the application.properties file will be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your Messages class seems to be a POJO that is not managed by Spring.
Only inside instances that are controlled by spring you can read application properties.